# How do I output multiple results of an operant at a time with 'alert'?

Tags: javascript

I'm absolutely new at JavaScript

```
  const number = prompt('Enter any number');
  const secondNumber = prompt('Enter any second number');
    x = number + secondNumber;
    x = number == secondNumber;
    x = number * secondNumber;
    x = number / secondNumber;
  alert(x);
```

Comment: use multiple alerts? One alert after each calculation.

Comment: Either concatenate the results in a string or push the results in an array, loop it and in each iteration alert the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define an object with key and value. Then add your result in it. Then you can use `JSON.stringify` to show all item of array in `alert`

```js
const number = prompt('Enter any number');
const secondNumber = prompt('Enter any second number');

 result = {};
    x = (number + secondNumber);
    result["+"] = x;
    x = number == secondNumber;
    result["=="] = x;
    x = (number * secondNumber);
    result["*"] = x;
    x = (number / secondNumber);
    result["/"] = x;
  alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: How do you know which expression produced which output? How to differentiate between addition, multiplication, etc. ?

Comment: I think OP's problem is show multiple item in one `alert` But if he wants to know ` which expression produced which output` he can use dictionary data structure